# How can i add a website page to resizable container

Tags: html, iframe, containers, resizable

I am really new to this: I have managed some content on a wordpress site but that is the extent of my knowledge.

I need to be able to present HTML code showcasing our website to customers: we have a calculator that will be demonstrated on other sites in a small container.

Here it is, it is also live as an iphone application; http://vcfmcalculator.co.uk/calculate/: http://vcfmcalculator.co.uk/calculate/

I have now researched and can use an iframe to present the site in a reduced and scaled size container however i would also like to be able to slot this into a resizable container.

I have an iframe, I have a resizable container but have no idea how to merge the 2!

here is my resizable container:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head><link f="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    #resizable { width: 100px; height: 100px; background: silver; }
  </style>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#resizable").resizable();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body style="font-size:62.5%;">

<div id="resizable"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

here is my iframe:

```
<iframe style="background: #ffffff; border: 4px solid #36939b;" src="http://vcfmcalculator.co.uk/calculate/" height="600" width="400" frameborder="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
<div>
```

Can this be done?

Please keep this simple as I will not understand your reply.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use [bootstrap responsive](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#responsive) maybe this resolve your problem...